# Restart to update fails silently

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS code version: 1.54.1
Platform: MacOS Catalina

Problem:

VS code indicates there is an update, both at left-bottom corner setting icon and a pop-up notification at right-bottom corner. But after I select "Restart to Update" from the menu, VS code exits and never restarts by itself, nor updates itself.

Then I restart VS code again, it is still the same version (1.54.1) and indicates an update available.

Question:

How to fix VS code so that "Restart to Update" can work?

Comment: Have you tried the solution to check if the app's in quarantine proposed in [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/7426#issuecomment-277737150)? Got that from a [similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/394038) on Ask Different.

Comment: @MihaiChelaru I've tried the solution you mentioned, but it did not work. Still have the same problem.

Comment: just a follow up, it turns out that after I restarted my MacBook, the problem is gone. (Only restarting VS code did not help).

Answer (score 0):

Close vs code and clear all code processes you might still have in the activity monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in a loop where the language server features were not
working right because of that; even with all windows closed, there
were actually background processes still present.

```
$ pgrep -lf vscode
51178 /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/
MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin) /Users/xxxxx/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2024.2.2/dist/
server.bundle.js --cancellationReceive=file:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --node-ipc --clientProcessId=xxxx
```

After killing the process

```
kill 51178
```

all the windows came back up.